# navigation div scroller

Tags: javascript, css, html, scroll

Hi i have this a div called "nav" that contains divs with a class "thumbs". Im trying to create a table of contents like div that can be scrolled to display further thumbnails.

this is my CSS so far: (note that each thumbs are position:absolute and is left: positioned accordingly)

```
#nav {
    position:absolute;
    width:768px;
    height:214px;
    bottom:0px;
    /*-webkit-transform:translateY(214px);*/
    background:gray;
    overflow:auto;
}
.thumbs {
    position:absolute;
    width:80px;
    height:100px;
    margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    background:white;
}
```

I want it to be scrollable so that if the thumbnails exceed 768px (width of nav) it can be scrolled to the left to view more.

Thanks

edit: I forgot to mention that I am doing this in PhoneGap. It will be a mobile app. thanks!

Comment: can you show an example in http://jsfiddle.net/ for better understanding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `position: absolute;` and add `float: left;` from your thumbs class. That should do it.

**UPDATE**

If the number of thumbs are known in advance, the inner div's width can be set via CSS. Otherwise, it can be set onload or whenever a thumb is added/removed via JS.

```
$('#div').css('width', ($('.thumbs').length * $('.thumbs:first').outerWidth(true)) + 'px');
```

Comment: didnt make a scroller sir. The thumbs just went below the first set :(

Comment: Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/techfoobar/xzcDD/ - I've added an outer div to make sure it scrolls.

Comment: That fiddle does assume a known width of the inner div and not an auto expanding example (what happens when his content is of variable length)?

Comment: If the number of thumbs are known in advance, the inner div's width can be set via CSS. Otherwise, it can be set onload or whenever a thumb is added/removed via JS - `$('#div').css('width', ($('.thumbs').length * $('.thumbs:first').outerWidth(true)) + 'px');` - Will update answer with that info as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the combination with `max-width`, `display:inline-block` & `white-space`.
Like this:

```
#nav_outer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    background:gray;
    overflow:auto;
}
#nav {
    height:214px;
    max-width: 300px;
    bottom:0px;
    /*-webkit-transform:translateY(214px);*/
    background:gray;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.thumbs {
    white-space:normal;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline; /*IE7*/
    *zoom:1; /*IE7*/
    width:80px;
    height:100px;
    margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    background:white;
}
```

### http://jsfiddle.net/xzcDD/3/

In my example when the `.thumbs less than the width of 300px` then there is `no scroll`